# AppNavItem in Vaadin is not marked as active after ui.navigate

Tags: routes, navigation, vaadin, menuitem

I am using latest version of Vaadin (v24).

AppNavItem is not marked as active after ui.navigate(SomeView1.class). SomeView1 is connected to the AppNavItem.

In my AppLayout class I have:

```
nav = new AppNav();

AppNavItem subNav = new AppNavItem("SomeClass1", SomeClass1.class);
nav.addItem(subNav);

AppNavItem subNav = new AppNavItem("SomeClass2", SomeClass2.class);
nav.addItem(subNav);
```

I SomeClass2 on button click I have this code:

```
this.getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(SomeClass1.class);
```

After clicking this button SomeClass2 AppNavItem is still marked as active. Is there a way to mark an item with current route as active in my navigation?

I tried this and still nothing happens and I'm not sure this is the right way:

```
@Override
public void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent p_event) {
     LOG.info(p_event.getLocation().getPath());
     List<AppNavItem> appNavItems = nav.getChildren()
             .map(item -> ((AppNavItem) item))
             .filter(item -> item.getPath().equals(p_event.getLocation().getPath()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
     if (!appNavItems.isEmpty()) {
         appNavItems.get(0).getElement().setAttribute("active", "active");
     }
}
```

Comment: Solved by upgrading Vaadin to 24.2.0
Found this issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/5157 which is resolved with this PR https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/17146

Comment: You can answer your own questions and that way get them resolved instead of leaving unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading Vaadin to 24.2.0 Found this issue github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/5157 which is resolved with this PR github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/17146